# Can you capture/sniff traffic from LCOW?

Tags: networking, docker, sniffing, traffic

Is it possible for a Linux container running on Windows (LCOW) to capture network traffic from the underlying Windows Container Host?

I.E. could `tcpdump` in the Linux container see the network traffic of the Windows host?

With a simple run of `alpine ash` under LCOW, `tcpdump` sees no traffic from Windows.

I am currently testing on Windows 10 Professional, using Docker Desktop. I believe I am using [Linux Containers with Hyper-V isolation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers#linux-containers-with-hyper-v-isolation) I would like to know if either forms of LCOW permit the container to capture host traffic.

Linux Containers on a Linux host *can* capture the desired host traffic, so long as the capturing container is [configured with host networking.](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) Is there a way to configure the VM that Docker uses in the background to permit the same ability on Windows?

The reason I believe this could be possible is that a regular Linux VM running on Windows can be configured to have a virtual network adapter that runs in `allow-all` promiscuous mode ([see final point on page here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)), which allows it to capture traffic of the underlying Windows host.

**Related questions:**

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/869
- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3596
- https://forums.docker.com/t/linux-containers-on-transparent-network/29733

Comment: [This windows doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/advanced#linux-containers-on-windows) may be relevant.

Comment: I am currently thinking the background Hyper-V Docker VM needs to be attached to an [External](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/architecture) vSwitch, with a [transparent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/network-drivers-topologies) driver backing the container's `--net` option. But attempts to make a transparent network resullt in `Error response from daemon: plugin "transparent" not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't capture the traffic of the Windows Host within a Linux Container.

please see: [link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers)

> **I cannot ping my containers**
>
> Docker Desktop for Windows can’t route traffic to Linux containers. However, you can ping the Windows containers.